# PyCharm indentation spaces

Tags: pycharm

How can I change indentation in pycharm to only 2 spaces instead of 4? My team follows the pep8, but chose to use 2 spaces instead of four, and I can't find anywhere to change it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Python (or "General" for all text files) -> Tabs and Indents (tab).

And there is a search tool in the top left corner of the settings window. You can use it to search any IDE setting.

Comment: Thanks, that works when pressing tab, but when I open a file it still indents by multiples of 4.

Comment: I think changing this settings will not change existing code in your project. It only actual for your new edits.

Comment: Sublime opens the same files and shows the tabs as a double space.

Answer (score 3):

You can set "tab size" to 2 and "indent" to 2. in the File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Python -> Tabs and Indents (tab)

check "Use tab character" in the File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Python -> Tabs and Indents (tab).Now the error or warning message like `PEP8: indentation contains tabs` will be removed. If the issue exist close the open files and reopen, or simply restart pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below steps to change the tab/indent size-

1. Go to `File -> Default Settings...`
2. A dialog box will appear, click on `Editor -> Code Style -> Python/Other File Types`
3. And set the **Tab/Indent size=2** present within right frame.

Below pics will help you more-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers:

You can also set the number of spaces in an `.editorconfig` file with `indent_size = <some integer>`.

[image]

I was working on a project for a company and having my Python files indented with two spaces instead of the 4 specified in my PyCharm settings, and it was because of this method of specifying the indentation.